# How to make a link clickable but also not?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, href, popover

So I'm working on my webshop and doing the final points to make it all good looking.

I thought you know what'd be cool? If there was a questionmark which said what you can search for. So few seconds later there it was.... but... you can't hover on mobile so I thought. Cheap fix. make it clickable. Which turns out wasn't a cheap fix because if you click on it, it links you to the top of the page. How do I make it that the popover is clickable, but leads to nowhere and also doesn't refresh the page or annything?

I got this so far:`

```
    <form method="GET" action="search.php#shop" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <a href="#" title="Zoektermen" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="left" data-content="U kunt zoeken op land, beschrijving, naam en merk."  >
        <p class="fa fa-question"></p>
      </a>
      <input id="form" name="id" type="text" placeholder="Producten zoeken" class="form-control" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zoekresultaten tonen</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

`

Kinda stuck here so help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance
P.S. Don't mind the text. It's Dutch :P

The script is:

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); }); </script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) plugin?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0) looks relevant

Comment: @DavidBarker I am using that but it still links.

Comment: @Rafi I really want to do the popover like the bootstrap kind since I use that one everywhere.

Comment: @JessieDenRidder `event.preventDefault()` in the closure would help.

Comment: @DavidBarker That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give it an id or class

```
<a href="#"  id="popover_button" title="Zoektermen" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="facous" data-placement="left" data-content="U kunt zoeken op land, beschrijving, naam en merk."  ></a>
```

Than disable the functionality with jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#popover_button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yep like someone commented on my original post. Tho he said to put it in the closure. I kinda like your way more because it looks cleaner in the code. Thanks!

Comment: @JessieDenRidder yes it's defenitly a very clean solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to the`<a>`nchor:

onclick="e.preventDefault();"

or

```
onclick="return false;"
```

or

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

It'd be easier if you provided the actual function being used.

```html
<form method="GET" action="search.php#shop" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <a href="#" title="Zoektermen" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="facous" data-placement="left" data-content="U kunt zoeken op land, beschrijving, naam en merk." onclick="e.preventDefault();">
    <p class="fa fa-question"></p>
  </a>
  <input id="form" name="id" type="text" placeholder="Producten zoeken" class="form-control" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zoekresultaten tonen</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean the JAVA? 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>

Or do you mean what the form does?

Comment: Yes, sir, the`<script>....</script>` But if you place one of those lines inside your `<a href=......</a>`, it should work. especially the last one.

Comment: Well that was the script :P `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); }); </script>` But if you look at the post I alreaddt got the answer. Thanks for you effort tho! I appreciate it!

Comment: This is what I see after a refresh.... https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDU1OTQwXzI0NTY4NTg

Comment: Woops all fixed now! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="#" title="Zoektermen"> My Text</a>`

This should work fine.

Comment: Nope thats exactly what I had in the first place without the popover :P @dDavidBarker had the answer I was looking for. Putting event.preventDefault() in the closure got it all fixed